# How To Delete EF Many To Many Relationship While Updating

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have 2 entities where I have many to many relationship with each other.

I have used the below code to generate the many to many relationship

```
Class A
{
    int ID
    public virtual ICollection<B> B;
}

Class B
{
    int ID;
    public virtual ICollection<A> A;
}
```

So obviously, EF generated another joining table for me automatically in the name of `AB` where I have `A_ID` and `B_ID`. And ofcourse, I do not have any class named `AB` and the `DBSet` for the same.

So while adding I either do `a.B.Add(b)` or `b.A.Add(a)`. Everything is fine upto this.

Now my query is, on updating A or B I need to remove all existing many-to-many entities and update A or B with new related entities.

For E.g. On updatation of A, I need to remove all B's and populate with new B's. Vice-versa for updation of B's, I need to remove all A's and insert new A's.

I tried removing all the existing entities as..

```
A a = db.A.Where(x => x.ID == 1);
a.B = new List<B>();
//Populate a.B with new B's as per requirement

db.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But this doesnot remove old entities. Instead insert the new B's that I populate. I also tried it as

```
A a = db.A.Where(x => x.ID == 1);
List<B> listB = new List<B>();
foreach(var b in a.B)
{
    listB.Add(db.B.Where(x => x.ID == b.ID);
}

foreach(var b in listB)
{
    a.B.Remove(b);
}

//Populate a.B with new B's as per requirement

db.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But it does the same.

I need to completely remove all the existing entities from AB table for the particular A in context and then populate with new B's.

Comment: In your first attempt, did you try starting with `A a = db.A.Include(x => x.B).Where(x => x.ID == 1);`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Ahh no. You mean lazy loading won't work here? Sure. Let me try that. I'll update you with the results :)